# Open Web Library

Tags: php, html, sql, database

so I have a library (physical) with around 20k books and I am in the process of digitalising these books (making them into pdfs by scanning).

I want to make an open library which can host all these 20k books with search, the search is not limited to book name but can also be author or publications.

I’ve thought of making a database initially with all the book entries and pointing it to the pdf. So when a book is searched, it goes through the database and has a download ready.

It would also be able to sort and display the dataset in alphabetical order making discovery of unknown books possible.

What would be the best way to do this, a database with books pointing to downloadable books in a file server?

Scope is to make something very similar to Anna’s archive

Help and suggestions to make this as simple as possible is very much appreciated.

Database with file server or only web based file server or a website holding everything internally (would be very tedious to make 20k pages)

Comment: (1) One of the ways - simply use a database table with columns like book name, author name, category, issue year, keywords and filename (filename points to the actual pdf file) (2) If you plan to allow public to access the books, make sure you are permitted by law (such as obtaining permissions from the copyright holders of the books)

Answer (score -1):

This seems like the perfect opportunity to do something I have been thinking about for a while. Due to the dataset being so small, I would consider having a redis database for fast access, sorting and just general reading that is a dupe of a persistent database of your choice, making reads lightning fast and writes not so much, but the impact is reduced by the frequency of both operations.

Please note that this is like using a chainsaw to cut flowers but it seemed like a very open question.